# Simple property of DFAs

Tags: automata, finite-automata, reference-request

Do you know if this simple property of a DFA is stated as a property (or theorem) in some Automata theory book (possibly with a particular name)?

**Property**: Given a DFA $A = \{ Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F \}$, if $w = uv$ and the state of $A$ on input $w$, after scanning $u$ is $q_i$ (when the head is at the beginning of subword $v$); and $A' = \{ Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_i, F \}$ then $w \in L(A)$ if and only if $v \in L(A')$

Comment: It seems so obvious that I doubt anyone would name it or call it a theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think I have spotted this property in a book. It uses the "extended" transition relation $\delta^*$, i.e., for strings rather than single letters.

> Other properties you would expect $\delta^*$ to satisfy can be derived from
>   our definition. For example, a natural generalization of the recursive
>   statement in the definition is the formula 
>   $$\delta^*(q,xy) = \delta^*(\delta^*(q,x),y))$$ 
>   which is true for every state $q$ and every two strings $x$ and $y$ in $\Sigma^*$.
>   The proof is by
>   structural induction on $y$ and is similar to the proof [...] in Example 1.27.
>
> John C. Martin, Introduction to Languages and the Theory of Computation, McGraw-Hill, 4th edition, c2011. Page 54.

I hope you agree with me that this matches the "machine" terminology you use in your question.